# Undefined offset error 3 in php

Tags: php

Can you please explain to me what an `Undefined Offset Error` is and why I'm getting one for the code below?

```
<?php
//random variables
$disallowed = array ("SELECT", "WHERE", "AND", "OR", "UPDATE", "DELETE");//THIS COULD     CAUSE AN ISSUE  
$ui="Zach's a doggy";//input
$ui2 = (explode(" ", $ui));//exploded
$count = count($ui2);
for($i=0;$i<=$count;$i++){
    echo $ui2[$i];
    echo $i;
    echo $ui2;
    echo $ui2[$i];
    $inbool=$ui2[$i];
    echo $inbool;
    if(in_array($inbool, $disallowed))  {
        switch ($inbool){
            case "SELECT";
                $ui2[$i]="%1";
                break;
            case "WHERE";
                $ui2[$i]="%2";
                break;
            case "AND";
                $ui2[$i]="%3";
                break;
            case "OR";
                $ui2[$i]="%4";
                break;
            case "UPDATE";
                $ui2[$i]="%5";
                break;
            case "DELETE";
                $ui2[$i]="%6";
                break;
        }
    }
}
return $ui2;
```

I've tried a lot of things, including those echo's to try to see what the error is and still have yet to come up with any explanation.

Comment: is this in a function?

Comment: was in a function, ya

Comment: was, or is? which is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the condition on your `for` loop like this

```
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){ // It is < and not <=
```

When you put `<=` , It will get into the loop when `$i` is 3. So eventually when your code reaches here

```
echo $ui2[$i];
```

It will search for the index `3` in the array which is a non-existence one , thus you get the `Undefined Offset` error.

Comment: oh, but this is before the fror loop

Comment: No Jake, Not possible at all, Run your code you will get the errors at line 8 , 10 and 11. If you change the condition as I said , you won't get any errors.